# HTML Table Padding not working

Tags: html

I have set up a simple table on my website - I used HTML code for the table - but I cannot figure out why the padding isn't working - I am using CSS and JS for the modal (I am a beginner). I even set the padding to 1000 and it doesn't do anything - the images stay right next to eachother. Here is my code:

```
  <table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="5">

<tr>

<td align="center" valign="center">
<a href="https://www.londonontariomortgages.ca/first time home buyer program.html"> <img id="myImg" src="table/first time home buyer.jpg" alt="First Time Home Buyer Ontario" style="width:100%;max-width:300px"> </a>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
<br />
<b>First Time Home Buyer Program<b>
</td>

<td align="center" valign="center">
<a href="https://www.londonontariomortgages.ca/renew my mortgage.html"> <img id="myImg" src="table/renewing your mortgage.jpg" alt="Renewing Your Mortgage" style="width:100%;max-width:300px"> </a>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
<br />
<b>Renewing Your Mortgage<b>
</td>


<td align="center" valign="center">
<a href="https://www.londonontariomortgages.ca/Guide to Getting a Mortgage.html"> <img id="myImg" src="table/guide to getting a mortgage.jpg" alt="Guide to Getting a Mortgage in London Ontario" style="width:100%;max-width:300px"> </a>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
<br />
<b>Guide to Getting a Mortgage<b>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If anyone could offer any suggestions it would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: where am I seeing css or the attribute `padding`?

Comment: Please edit your question with clear code.

Answer (score 1):

For table you can't give padding., for 'div' and other element such as "P, span" you can give padding. For table use cellpadding. (If you want to see just put border value as 1 then you can see padding with border.)

Answer (score -4):

I would suggest you to set margin for the table rather than padding and i hope that it might work...

Comment: I tried changing it to    <table width="500" border="0" style="margin-right:50px"> and it stayed the same - Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score -4):

Yes use margin rather than padding and visit this site to know more about them:
http://www.htmldog.com/references/css/properties/padding/